# Android 2.2 VideoView problem

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to play a movie from my sd-card. Ive tried using the following code:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/robot.avi");

MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

videoView.setVideoPath(MEDIA_PATH);

videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

videoView.start();
```

But when Im trying to play the file i get an error message. "video not found" or something similar. When i tried streaming from the web, the video worked but was very laggy. Whats the best way to play videos in my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try this...

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sdcard/robot.avi");

MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

videoView.setVideoPath(MEDIA_PATH);

videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 5):

It is observed that `setVideoPath()` fails, while `setVideoURI()` works well for both *Web and Local* so I insist you to use this.

```
 VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("file:///sdcard/robot.avi");

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    videoView.setVideoURI(MEDIA_PATH);

    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code.Hope it will work

```
public class VideoPlayActivity extends Activity {
private VideoView video;
private MediaController ctlr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

File clip=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
               "haha.mp4");


if (clip.exists()) {
video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());

ctlr=new MediaController(this);
ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
video.setMediaController(ctlr);
video.requestFocus();
video.start();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
video_view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

you can not pass directly as a string path if you are trying to set as a uri. The  code which is working fine for me :

```
    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/file_name";

    // Add controls to a MediaPlayer like play, pause.
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    video_view.setMediaController(mc);

    // Set the path of Video or URI.
    video_view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));

    // Set the focus.
    video_view.requestFocus();

    video_view.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

your problem is that the video path is not set the right way:

just switch to this code:

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/robot.avi";
```

that will solve your problem if the video "robot.avi" exists on the root folder of the sd card

Answer (score 2):

May be avi does not support in android.convert  it into mp4 or wmv or 3gp.
try this code

```
public class VideoPlayActivity extends Activity {
 private VideoView video;
 private MediaController ctlr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

File clip=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                   "robot.mp4");

if (clip.exists()) {
  video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
  video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());

  ctlr=new MediaController(this);
  ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
  video.setMediaController(ctlr);
  video.requestFocus();
  video.start();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are playing your video in your own `VideoView`,
But if you have nothing to customize and just want to show the video in the screen,why dont you use the default player to play the video.

```
File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"FileName");
//make sure the video is in SDCard, 
//if its located in any folder care to pass full absolute path 
Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(imgFile.getPath()), "video/*");
startActivity(tostart);
```